# What would the impact be on the physics world if neutrinos DO travel faster than light?

Tags: special-relativity, faster-than-light, neutrinos

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What would be the immediate effects if light does not go at the maximum speed possible?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14973/what-would-be-the-immediate-effects-if-light-does-not-go-at-the-maximum-speed-pos)
>   [Superluminal neutrinos](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14968/superluminal-neutrinos)

I was reading this [article](http://hosted.ap.org/dynamic/stories/E/EU_BREAKING_LIGHT_SPEED?SITE=AP&SECTION=HOME&TEMPLATE=DEFAULT) about a group of scientist thinking that they might have surpassed the speed of light with neutrinos, and are wanting other groups to check their work.

If their research is proven true, what impact would this finding have on the world of physics?

Comment: As much as I hate to close a good question like this, I think you really did ask pretty much the same thing as a couple of earlier questions.

Comment: ...and I looked too....

Comment: Sometimes we miss the most obvious things ;-) (If those other questions aren't satisfying your curiosity, feel free to edit this one to specify what you'd like to know that isn't covered by those others. As far as I'm concerned, the more questions about current research, the better.)