# What are the implications of superliminal neutrinos?

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos, faster-than-light

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What would be the immediate effects if light does not go at the maximum speed possible?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14973/what-would-be-the-immediate-effects-if-light-does-not-go-at-the-maximum-speed-pos)
>   [Superluminal neutrinos](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14968)

Do we re-write physics? Or can it be fitted in current theories? I always hear about Lorentz violation in Plank scale or somewhere there. But what about this?

Comment: Good question, but we've already had the exact same thing asked already a couple of times. (If the earlier questions don't cover what you want to know about it, feel free to edit this one to focus on exactly what else you'd like to know.)

Comment: It would become of great interest to map the neutrino flux around the Earth, for that neutrino flux would almost certainly contain messages from the future.