# Neutrinos and the Cosmic Speed Limit

Tags: speed-of-light, neutrinos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Superluminal neutrinos](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14968/superluminal-neutrinos)

An article in the newspaper a few months ago said that Neutrinos travel faster than Light. Another article then said that this observation was flawed due to faults in the electrical systems. Is this true? And if not, will this lead to redefining the Cosmic Speed Limit (*c*) as proposed by Einstein?

Comment: What does this have to do with the cosmological constant?

Comment: The centralized Physics.SE question for all things relating the OPERA superluminal-neutrinos result is http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14968/superluminal-neutrinos. And you can find many others by [searching for "OPERA"](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=opera).

Comment: It is important to note that nobody--including the members of the OPERA collaboration--took that result as definitive. The assumptions was that it was a mistake and the speculation about evenly divide between *what the mistake might have been* and *what if* papers.