# Concerning a previous possible tachyon observation?

Tags: special-relativity, faster-than-light, neutrinos, tachyon

A few years ago there was a story about the Large Hadron Collider where a possible tachyon  was supposedly observed. It was later shown it didn't occur yet the incident made me think. If a large experiment using extreme amounts of energy trying to duplicate some processes or events of the 'distant' past , would the intense amount of energy  in this 'early' Universe experiment create a situation where the speed of light was different?? If a particle was observed emanating from this experiment and it seemed superluminal could this be due to a different speed of light measurement due to this phenomenon.

Comment: Are you talking about the [OPERA neutrinos](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14968/superluminal-neutrinos)? That had absolutely nothing to do with the LHC (and as the answer explains, was shown to be a faulty measurement).

Comment: To be very clear, OPERA involved CERN, but the LHC is not CERN. LHC is *at* CERN, but it is only one of a great many things at CERN. OPERA's neutrino beam was produced by a different accelerator (the SPS).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this result was later found to be caused by faulty electronics, according to the [CERN press release](http://press-archived.web.cern.ch/press-archived/PressReleases/Releases2011/PR19.11E.html).